# TextButton change text color on button down?

Tags: java, json, libgdx, scene2d

How can I change the text color of a button when I am over it, pressing it or having it cancelled out?

```
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
        default: { down: round-down, up: round, font: default-font },
    },
```

Here I can set the default buttons texture on down, up etc and the font used for all. I want the button to change the font color or the font as a whole for each different state. Is this possible within the skin's json file?

I know how to create this programmatically with ui styles. I just like the convenience of having it in the skin.